# display words which words length is more than 8

Tags: scala

I am trying to get from below list where the words have r and size should be more than 8 and converted to uppercase all the values in the list.

```
val names=List("sachinramesh","rahuldravid","viratkohli","mayank")
```

But I have tried with below but it is not giving anything. It throwing error.

`names.map(s =>s.toUpperCase.contains("r").size(8)`

It is throwing error.
can someone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: 1) You're missing a closing paren: `)` 2) After the string is made uppercase it cannot contain an "r". 3) `.size` doesn't take a parameter. You want `.filter()`.

Comment: It doesn't even compile.I would recommend to first carefully read the scaladoc.

Comment: `names.filter(s ⇒ s.contains("r") && s.length > 8).map(_.toUpperCase)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing a combination of `filter` and `map`, think about using the `collect` method, which does both in one call. This is how to do what is described in the question:

```
names.collect{
  case s if s.lengthCompare(8) > 0 && s.contains('r') =>
    s.toUpperCase
}
```

`collect` works like `filter` because it only returns values that match a `case` statement. It works like `map` because you can make changes to the matching values before returning them.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
 names.filter(str => str.contains('r') && str.length > 8) // str contains an `r` and length > 8
    .map(_.toUpperCase) // map the result to uppercase
```

Comment: A string contains `Char` (not `String`)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick reply and it is working perfectly. can you explain why we you used _ after map method

Comment: @Kumar the `_` is a syntactic sugar in Scala. You can either do `.map(word => word.toUppercase)` or just do `.map(_.toUppercase)`

Comment: `String` also has a contains method that works for `String` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

`names.filter(...).map(...)` approach solves the problem, however requires iterating through the list twice. For a more optimal solution where we go through the list only once, consider @Tim's suggestion regarding `collect`, or perhaps consider lazy `Iterator` approach like so:

```
names
  .iterator
  .filter(_.size > 8)
  .filter(_.contains('r'))
  .map(_.toUpperCase)
  .toList
```

Comment: May the downvoter explain what is wrong with the answer? It is perfectly fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
val result =for (x <- names if x.contains('r') && x.length > 8) yield x.toUpperCase
result.foreach(println)
```

cheers